# Searching and printing output in multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am learning about arrays in PHP. I am working on multidimensional arrays in which I am facing an issue.

Here is an illustration of sample multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [venue] => chicago
            [course] => science
            [time] => 2pm
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
             [venue] => New York
             [course] => Robotics
             [time] => 3 p.m.
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
             [venue] => New York
             [course] => Science
             [time] => 4 p.m.
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
             [venue] => Chicago
             [course] => Robotics
             [time] => 4 p.m.
        )
)
```

The Desired output that I want to print from the above array is:

```
Chicago
Science  2 p.m.
Robotics  4 p.m. 

New York 
Science 4 p.m.
Robotics 3 p.m.
```

Can anyone guide me how can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to first sort the array by venue. `usort` can be used for that.

```
usort($events, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['venue'], $b['venue']);
});
```

After the array is sorted, you can iterate it, and output a header each time you get to a new venue.

```
$previousVenue = null;
foreach ($events as $event) {

    // check if this venue is the same as the previous, output header if not
    if ($event['venue'] != $previousVenue) {
        echo "<h3>$event[venue]</h3>";
    }
    // always output course and time
    echo "$event[course] $event[time]<br>";

    // current venue becomes previous venue
    $previousVenue = $event['venue'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array for each venue and store course and time as key and values respectively

```
// define an array
$new_array = array();
// loop the array
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    // create an array with each venue and  course and time as key and values
    $new_array[$value['venue']][$value['course']] = $value['time'];
}
```

Loop the new array and display the results as per your desire.

```
// loop the new array
foreach($new_array as $key=>$value){
    echo $key."\n";  // echo the venue
    krsort($value);  // Sort an array by key in reverse order
    foreach($value as $k=>$v){
        echo $k . ' ' . $v."\n"; // echo the course and time
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Out Put

```
chicago
science 2pm
robtics 4pm

newyork
science 4pm
robotics 3pm
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a foreach to get your result as below.

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['venue']."<br>";
    echo $row['firstname']."  ".$row['lastname'];
}
```